# View Database (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, database

I have SQLDBX, And it works perfectly for MSSQL, but it doesn't work for MySQL. And I would like to know if any of you know of any database viewers that can connect to MySQL database on a server? Just something simple I guess, doesn't have to be brilliant, just has to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try: [MySQL Query Browser](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/query-browser/en/)

Answer (score 0):

I love this: http://www.heidisql.com/

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of them : [SQLYog](http://www.webyog.com/en/downloads.php), [MySQL Query Browser](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/query-browser/en/). I even use [Oracle SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html) (with MySQL extension) to view MySQL.